# Facebook FQL: Strange Status Query

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-fql

I am executing this fql query

```
SELECT status_id,message FROM status WHERE uid  IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by rand() limit 10
```

the result I get is just few statuses (about 4), instead of the 10 I asked for, and they are always the same, instead of being random as I asked.

Any advice?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Con you confirm that you have at least 10 friends?

Comment: If you do - have at least 10 friends - can you confirm that they are using/have granted view rights to your application in which you are executing your query?

Comment: rand() seems to be OK if you have more items in the resultset then the number specified at 'limit' -> in your you have less items then the resultset then the limit and therefore no 'random' behavior really happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT  status_id, message
FROM    status
WHERE   uid IN ( 
SELECT   uid2 LIMIT 10
FROM     Friend
WHERE    uid=me())
ORDER BY rand()